# How can I return a value from an function that is executed from tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

Just started learning Python.
I have created a file containing a class with tkinter fuctions.

For Example:

**file1.py:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import os
class flt:
    def func(var):
        var['file'] = pd.read_excel(os.getcwd()+'\\xyz.xlsx')
        if var[ch].get()==1:
            var['file'] = "Filter this file accordingly"   # Example
        if var[hc].get()==1:
            var['file'] = "filter this file accordingly"   #Example
        return var['file']     #I want this value in file2.py
    def do_something(var):
        root = var['root']
        mainframe = var['mainframe']
        var[ch] = IntVar()
        var[hc] = IntVar()
        ch1 = Checkbutton(mainframe, text='Filter by ABC',variable=var[ch])
        ch2 = Checkbutton(mainframe, text='Filter by 123', variable=var[ch])
        ch1.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2)
        ch2.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.3)
        bt = tk.Button(mainframe, text='submit', command=lambda: flt.func(var))
        bt.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
```

And the another file, say **file2.py:**

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
mainframe = tk.Frame(root, relief='raised')
mainframe.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, width='1100', height='380')
val = {}
val['root'] = root
val['mainframe'] = mainframe
def chk:
    import file1
    value = file1.do_something(val)
    print(value)
btn = tk.Button(mainframe, text='Check', command = chk)
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8)
root.mainloop()
```

I want the value "var['file']" (from func(var)>file1.py) in file2.py
Every Answer is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: in you `file2.py` import like `from file2 import flt`. Make sure both the files are in same location

Comment: Your code is riddled with errors. You should update your question with either the full error traceback, or the corrected code.

Comment: @Epsi95 both files are located in same location and yeah i do used import like `from file1 import flt` but the above code is an example. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @quamrana the original code is of 100s of lines. In this code i do agree that there may be many errors, but my question is there any way to get the value from another class in file when called from a tkinter button? Thank you

Comment: Well, reading between the lines in the code you supply, it is up to the user to press the `submit` button. So when they do that (execute `flt.func()`) what do you want to happen in `file1.py`?

Comment: @quamrana In file2.py a base window is created, when a user presses show button, file2.py creates some widgets on the same window, and after the data is entered by user in file2.py widgets, I want the value (in flt.func(x)) to be returned in file2.py for further processing.

Comment: You mean that there will be a function in `file2.py` which will do the processing?  (I may have mixed up `file1/file2` in previous comments).

Comment: @quamrana yes you got it correct. I am updating my question for more... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep making your code more and more complicated and I still don't understand what you want.

So, I made this minimal program to show that when its the case that a new button appears, and the user presses that button, that a value is calculated and used in a call to an arbitrary function from another module:
**file1.py**

```py
import tkinter as tk

def func(var):
    var['file'] = 42
    return var['file']

def do_something(var, f):
    # root = var['root']
    mainframe = var['mainframe']
    bt = tk.Button(mainframe, text='submit', command=lambda: f(func(var)))
    # When the user presses submit, the function f is called with the 'return' value
    bt.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
```

**file2.py**

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
mainframe = tk.Frame(root, relief='raised')
mainframe.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, width='1100', height='380')
val = {}
val['root'] = root
val['mainframe'] = mainframe

def f(value):
    print(value)   # Just prints the value, but could do anything!
    
def chk():
    import file1
    file1.do_something(val, f)  # f passed from here as a callback
    # Note - no return value

btn = tk.Button(mainframe, text='Check', command = chk)
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8)
root.mainloop()
```

**Note:** the frame starts small and you need to drag it to resize it bigger to see the buttons.

Comment: Yeah but it's more complicated on my side. But this solved my problem, thanks a ton @quamrana

Answer (score 0):

Here first you have to create the respective class and then import the file.

**File1:**

```
#creating a class
class person:
    def __init__ f1(self,x):# this function will be called everytime when the class is called
        self.value=x
```

**File2:**

```
import file1    #importing the file (file name)
x=file1.person(10)#calling the class from file1 (parameter given as 10)
print(x.value)  #printing the value.
```

---

In your case:

**file 1:**

```
import tkinter as tk
class flt:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.value = x*x

    def do_something(self,var):
        #some stuff
```

**file 2:**

```
import file1
import tkinter as tk

#basic tkinter window code

trial=file1.flt('value')
test=trial.value #here you store the value of file1

def chk:
    value = file1.do_something(val)
    print(value)
btn = tk.Button(mainframe, text='Check', command = chk)
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8)
root.mainloop()
```